# Cover letter to explain missing requirement for Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, h1b-visas

I plan to apply for a (Greece) Schengen visa in USA. I am on the H1b visa.

Schengen visas lodged in the US seem to require that my US visa is valid for 3 months after the date of departure for Schengen area. I will not satisfy this requirement. However, I have a valid i797 showing that I am allowed to get my US visa extended for 3 years.

I plan to get the extended visa stamped a month after my Schengen trip, when I will be visiting my home country.

If I submit a cover letter explaining this situation (and a copy of the i797), will that suffice?